# Replace function in access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two strings like

```
 str1= "[abc 1],[def 2],[ghi 3],[jkl 4],[mno 5]"
 str2="[def 2],[mno 5]"
```

The strings in str2 [def 2],[mno 5] should be deleted or replaced with "" in str1. result will be

```
str1="[abc 1],[ghi 3],[jkl 4]"
```

I tried replace function but not working giving full string str1

```
strorg1 = Replace(str1, str2,"")
```

Comment: You could use SPLIT on string2 and iterate through the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (sorry for not being able to format as code by now)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim str As Variant

    str1 = "[abc 1],[def 2],[ghi 3],[jkl 4],[mno 5]"
    str2 = "[def 2],[mno 5]"

    str1 = "|" & str1 & "|"
    For Each str In Split(str2, ",")
        str1 = Replace(str1, str, "")
    Next str
    str1 = Replace(Replace(Replace(str1, ",,", ","), "|,", ""), ",|", "")
    MsgBox str1
End Sub
```

Comment: please may i know why did u add "|" for str1

Comment: For marking the beginning and end of it and easily remove possible trailing commas. Try without! Did it work for you?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good coding!

Answer (score 2):

This works i think:

```
Option Explicit
Sub gen()
    Dim ReplaceList(1 To 5) As String
    Dim str1 As String, strToReplace As Variant
    Dim a() As String
    Dim element As Long

    str1 = "[abc 1],[def 2],[ghi 3],[jkl 4],[mno 5]"
    ReplaceList(1) = "[def 2]"
    ReplaceList(2) = "[mno 5]"

    a = Split(str1, ",")

    For element = UBound(a) To 0 Step -1
        For Each strToReplace In ReplaceList

            If a(element) = strToReplace Then
                a(element) = ""
            End If
        Next
    Next
    str1 = Join(a)
    Debug.Print str1
End Sub
```

edit, i don't have access to Access, I hope this works, if not it should set you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim strTemp As String
Dim strTemp2 As String
Dim strOut As String
str1 = "[abc 1],[def 2],[ghi 3],[jkl 4],[mno 5]"
str2 = "[def 2],[mno 5]"
strOut = str1
Do
    strTemp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("]", str2)
    strTemp2 = Mid(str2, 1, strTemp + 1)
    strOut = Replace(strOut, strTemp2, "")
    str2 = Replace(str2, strTemp2, "")
Loop Until str2 = ""
End Sub
```

It will parse your str2, cut pieces inside [] and remove it from str1 one by one.

The output is what you expected, using excel 2010.

Comment: *Range("A2").Select* and *Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("]", str2)* not access vba functions

Comment: then state explicitly you want an access vba solution. you can remove the range.Select . I let you search an equivalent of the search function, since it won't be complicated to find.

Comment: *"then state explicitly you want an access vba solution"* - look at the question?